# how to get ID values at grid view RowCreated event

Tags: c#, asp.net, t-sql

I have one code to display Promotional,Transactional and Optin balance. here I post code to how I achive this :

```
    protected void egrd_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                string ID = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ID") as string;

//cant get this ID as string returns null

                Literal ltr = e.Row.FindControl("ltrbalance") as Literal;

                string str = "";
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                str = "SELECT       a.[ID] ,a.[strUserName],";
                str += " (select intCurrentBalance from accountmappings where intUserID = a.[ID] and intAccountType = 1 ) as Prm_Balance ";
                str += " ,(select intCurrentBalance from accountmappings where intUserID = a.[ID] and intAccountType = 2 ) as Trn_Balance ";
                str += " ,(select intCurrentBalance from accountmappings where intUserID = a.[ID] and intAccountType = 3 ) as Opt_Balance ";
                str += " FROM users a where ID='"+ID+"'";
                dt = obj.Get_Data_Table_From_Str(str);

                switch (ddl_accounttype.SelectedItem.Text.ToString())
                {
                    case "All":
                        ltr.Text = "<SPAN>Promotional : " + dt.Rows[0]["Prm_Balance"].ToString() + " </br> Transactional : " + dt.Rows[0]["Trn_Balance"].ToString() + " <br/> Optin : " + dt.Rows[0]["Opt_Balance"].ToString() + "</SPAN>";
                        break;
                    case "Promotional":
                        ltr.Text = "<SPAN>Promotional : " + dt.Rows[0]["Prm_Balance"].ToString() + " </SPAN>";
                        break;
                    case "Transactional":
                        ltr.Text = "<SPAN>Transactional : " + dt.Rows[0]["Trn_Balance"].ToString() + "</SPAN>";
                        break;
                    case "OptIn":
                        ltr.Text = "<SPAN>Optin : " + dt.Rows[0]["Opt_Balance"].ToString() + "</SPAN>";
                        break;
                    default:
                        ltr.Text = "<SPAN>Promotional : " + dt.Rows[0]["Prm_Balance"].ToString() + " </br> Transactional : " + dt.Rows[0]["Trn_Balance"].ToString() + " <br/> Optin : " + dt.Rows[0]["Opt_Balance"].ToString() + "</SPAN>";
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

how can I achieve this I can't get it now. please help me out guys...

Comment: what is the type of ID field in the database?

Comment: a.[ID] this is first binds ID value to DataKeyNames as ID

Comment: @Andrei do you have any idea how I achieve this.

Comment: @Andrei-please see my update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. I just found new solution with code but can't get result as expected.

```
 protected void egrd_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow gvr in egrd.Rows)
        {
            string val = egrd.DataKeys[gvr.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString();

            Literal ltr = egrd.FindControl("ltrbalance") as Literal;

            string str = "";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            str = "SELECT       a.[ID] ,a.[strUserName],";
            str += " (select intCurrentBalance from accountmappings where intUserID = a.[ID] and intAccountType = 1 ) as Prm_Balance ";
            str += " ,(select intCurrentBalance from accountmappings where intUserID = a.[ID] and intAccountType = 2 ) as Trn_Balance ";
            str += " ,(select intCurrentBalance from accountmappings where intUserID = a.[ID] and intAccountType = 3 ) as Opt_Balance ";
            str += " FROM users a where ID='" + int.Parse(val) + "'";

            dt = obj.Get_Data_Table_From_Str(str);

            switch (ddl_accounttype.SelectedItem.Text.ToString())
            {
                case "All":

                    ltr.Text = "<SPAN>Promotional : " + dt.Rows[0]["Prm_Balance"].ToString() +
                               " </br> Transactional : " + dt.Rows[0]["Trn_Balance"].ToString() +
                               " <br/> Optin : " + dt.Rows[0]["Opt_Balance"].ToString() + "</SPAN>";
                    break;
                case "Promotional":
                    ltr.Text = "<SPAN>Promotional : " + dt.Rows[0]["Prm_Balance"].ToString() + " </SPAN>";
                    break;
                case "Transactional":
                    ltr.Text = "<SPAN>Transactional : " + dt.Rows[0]["Trn_Balance"].ToString() + "</SPAN>";
                    break;
                case "OptIn":
                    ltr.Text = "<SPAN>Optin : " + dt.Rows[0]["Opt_Balance"].ToString() + "</SPAN>";
                    break;
                default:
                    ltr.Text = "<SPAN>Promotional : " + dt.Rows[0]["Prm_Balance"].ToString() +
                               " </br> Transactional : " + dt.Rows[0]["Trn_Balance"].ToString() +
                               " <br/> Optin : " + dt.Rows[0]["Opt_Balance"].ToString() + "</SPAN>";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

and result shows like this way :

[image]

here first rows data goes to second line...

Comment: Aside: Are you proud of the heading on your web page? I suspect that the page heading, and including the whole Paint window, won't help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

First off, even if the value of ID doesn't came from an input, you should never append the filter parameter to your SQL query as it can leads you to SQL Injection attack. You should use parameterize query for security: http://vmsdurano.com/protect-your-data-prevent-sql-injection/

Now to your question,

> here first rows data goes to second line...

Just apply an [Order By](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) clause to your SQL query based on date or to whatever field that you want the result to be sorted.